# Как сделать движение объекта вверх на определённое количество секунд при срабатывании триггера?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пробовал уже многие варианты, но ничего не работает. Вот последняя догадка:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ElevatorScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject elev;
    public Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.up;
    public float speed;
    public float ttime;
    float uspeed = 0;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if(col.tag == "Player")
        {
            StartCoroutine(ControlDirection(ttime));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ControlDirection(float ietime)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(ietime);
            uspeed = speed;
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        elev.transform.Translate(moveVector * uspeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: я так понимаю, вы заходите в лифт и через условные две секунды он должен поехать вверх, да ? А что происходит у вас  ?

Answer (score 2):

Вы, в принципе, верной дорогой шли. Вот вам пример корутины, которая может сделать то, что вам нужно:

```
IEnumerator ControlDirection(float moveTime)
{
    float timeLeft = 0;
    while(timeLeft <= moveTime)
    {
        timeLeft += Time.deltaTime;
        elev.transform.Translate(moveVector * uspeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Т.е. мы присылаем в корутину время, в течении которого наш герой должен двигаться. Внутри неё запускается цикл, который будет продолжаться до тех пор пока переменная `timeLeft` не станет больше нужного нам времени.

Каждую итерацию цикла мы прибавляем к `timeLeft` `Time.deltaTime` (это время обработки последнего кадра), затем сдвигаем юнита, а потом с помощью `yield return null` ждём до начала следующего кадра, и уже в нём начинаем следующую итерацию.

Comment: Правильный ответ, но фраза "пропускаем кадр" сбивает с толку, как-то она не органично звучит имхо, но в целом +.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, не пришло в голову, как выразить иначе, чтоб было понятно без дополнительных пояснений) есть ещё мысли? А то может подменю

Comment: Да я вот сам не знаю, как правильно мысль выразить. После беглого прочтения ответа сложилось впечатление, что корутина через раз кадр пропускает и ничего не делает, именно из-за этого фразы. По сути, это можно назвать выходом из "апдейта", который корутина и эмулирует, но это лютое округление и другие пользователи-новички могут просто не понять, так что пусть лучше будет так, как сейчас написано :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, хм. Подправил немного

Comment: Вот, сейчас максимально разжевано для новичков, отлично.

Comment: Но у меня эта корутина не работает. Я написал StartCoroutine в OnTriggerEnter

Comment: @f4lconak, А у вас вообще происходит OnTriggerEnter?)

Comment: Да, я добавил Debug.Log и он выводит в консоль

Comment: @f4lconak, сама корутина верна и делаем именно то, о чем вы просили. значит проблема в том, как вы её используете. Учитесь дебажить код, вставляйте брейк поинты, смотрите значения переменных, добавляйте дополнительные консольные выводы